# DateTime.ParseExact String not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

After having spent long hours trying various suggestions found here in SO as well as through out google, I turn the SO community.

I have an Asp.Net project that read data from a Database into poco classes. I cannot convert a string value representing a DateTime into the appropriate value in c#. Here is my code:

```
string value = get_value_from_repository(fieldname, repository); 
// value = "21/1/2015 12:00:00 πμ" which means 21-jan-2015 12:00:00 am (greek)

DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

No matter what format I try to use ("dd/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt") I still get this error. Any suggestion toward the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `πμ` doesn't mean pm? (Sorry, I know that's no help...)

Comment: How is `πμ` culture invariant? Maybe you should use Greek culture-info?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in Invariant culture, which would not recognise the Greek characters for "am" - that's my guess. Try a Greek CultureInfo object instead (possibly CurrentCulture if it's set correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the greek `DateTimeFormat`:

```
var greek = new CultureInfo("el-GR").DateTimeFormat;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", greek, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This works as expected and returns 21-jan-2015. If the greek `DateSeparator` would not be `/` you also need to use `'/'` instead since [`/` are replaced with the localized date separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator).

Comment: Thank! your suggestion solved my problem. In my tables in my Database the date is store like "2015-01-21", I guest when .Net framework reads this value, it translates it into string "21/1/2015 12:00:00 πμ". Is there a global way to tell framework to write "21/1/2015 12:00:00 am"?

Comment: No need to escape `/` character Tim :). `el-GR` has `/` as a `DateSeparator`.

Comment: @SonerGönül: yes, i've noticed it. That's why i've mentioned _"If the greek DateSeparator would not be / you also need to use '/' instead"_ I mentioned it anyway in case he needs to convert other culture's dates as well.